# Passing data through segue via navigation controller - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Really hoping someone can help as I feel like I have tried every option I could find on SC. First sorry if the code is messy or this is a dumb question, development isn't my strongest point :/

Basically I have an iPad specific app created in storyboard, I have a number of view controllers and scenes and have embedded a navigation controller. The app is very linear and it just moves through each screen in order (you can't jump about within the app at all).

On the first screen there are 2 selections that the user can make via 2 buttons, these each display an image and whichever images they choose need to also be displayed on each of the next screens.

When I didn't have a navigation controller embedded it worked just fine by calling the following:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"passSegue"] && (parentImage.hidden == NO) && (parentImage2.hidden == NO)) {
    ViewControllerGirl2 * vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    UIImage *imageView = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/1.png"]];
    UIImage *imageView2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/2.png"]];
    vc.parentImage = imageView;
    vc.parentImage2 = imageView2;    
}
```

But now I have embedded in a UINavigationController my images no longer appear on the next screen. I have tried the suggested methods of:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
ViewControllerGirl2 *vc = (ViewControllerGirl2 *)navController.topViewController;
```

But every way I tried to implement those suggestions it crashed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for 2 days solid.

Comment: what does it say when it crashes? I mean the debug output if any?

Comment: Hi @EugeneZhenyaGordin it says:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewControllerGirl2 topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c9c13b0'

Comment: so is the destinationViewController a UINavigationController or ViewControllerGirl2 for you ? look in the debug through a breakpoint, cause I think you're doing the wrong casting there....the error tells you that ViewControllerGirl2 doesn't have the method topViewController, so I assume destinationViewController is already ViewControllerGirl2

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin It's ViewControllerGirl2. Thank you for your feedback, it's really appreciated. 
The only reason I added in the nav controller was due to excessive memory allocation on modal presentation of each VC and I needed a way of removing view controllers off the stack to free up memory :/ I'm sure what I have done is a bit silly!

Comment: so did you resolve your problem? when you're using just destinationViewController without nav controller reference?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin When I wasn't using the nav controller the prepare for segue worked fine and as expected (using a modal segue) but I couldn't resolve the memory issue, so I embedded the nav controller and have fixed memory issues but now have this problem instead :/ I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

As a fast workaround (if you subclassed your UINavigationController) you can add parentImage properties to it, and inside of the prepare for segue assign your image values to those properties of the navigation controller. Then in the viewWillAppear of the destination view controller, you can do:

```
self.parentImage = yourNavController.yourImageProperty1;
self.parentImage2 = yourNavController.yourImageProperty1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I still don't seem to be able to get the prepare for segue to work correctly, or are you suggesting scrapping the prepare for segue completely?

Answer (score 0):

i thing destination view controller is navigation conteoller. Try this out

UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];

viewControllerGirl2 *vc2= (ShowItemsTableViewController *)([navController viewControllers][0]);

Hope this helps you. .

Comment: Thanks, but it has the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

prepareforsegue used for instantiate the controllers, and not UI properties, but if you need set the UI properties you use the viewDidLoad of parent:

```
// in interface declare this
@property (nonatomic, weak) ViewControllerGirl2 *childViewController;

// in viewDidLoad
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    self.childViewController.parentImage = image;
}

// in segue
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerGirl2 class]]) {
        self. childViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

prepareforsegue runs before viewDidLoad, you can also use viewWillAppear in its place, but only for this case